# Export View to PDF using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I'm working in MVC5. I have a view that shows a barcode:

```
 public ActionResult generarBardCode()
    {

        barcodecs objbar = new barcodecs();

        Byte[] arr = objbar.getBarcodeImage("784125", "alder");
        ViewBag.BarCode = "data:image/jpg;base64," + 
        Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])arr);            
        return View();
    } 



   and here is mi methos to export pdf


     public ActionResult Export()
    {
        barcodecs objbar = new barcodecs();
        Byte[] arr = objbar.getBarcodeImage("784125", "alder");

        string contenido = "data:image/jpg;base64," + 
       Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])arr);
        string inputText = "alder";
        string checkedValues = "<img src="+contenido+" />";//how put here mi 
        view?

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
            Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, 
            BaseColor.BLUE);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(inputText));
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(checkedValues));
            doc.Close();
            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();

            //Response.Clear();
            //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
            filename=Employee.pdf");
            //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            //Response.Buffer = true;
            //Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            //Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            //Response.End();
            //Response.Close();

            return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "fileName.pdf");
        }
    }
```

how i can render the view into my export method? 
in this line i add content directly but i want include the view method here
string checkedValues = "";//how put here mi 
        view?

Comment: Your `Byte[] arr` contains the bitmap image in question.  How about creating an iTextSharp image from it and adding that image to the `Document doc`?

Comment: Hi Rouning .I actually try. But did not work. the document show me the image as a string

like this <img
src=data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOYAAABwCA
YAAAAKVQzlAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcE
hZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAhaSURBVHhe7ZsBbhtHDEV9PB1Ix/FdfBXf
RJ0lh9Lyc+lJAzSaoO/>